# How to prevent Ignite from "dying" if first attempt to join the cluster failed?

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose, ignite

I'm using `docker-compose` to start several containers with java web application with embedded Ignite 2.6.

I configured Ignite so it will use SSL.

If I start node1 and wait it to fully start, and then start node2, they will join cluster no problem.

But if I start them simultaneously (that's how it works by default with docker-compose) they both will fail with exception and will never retry or get back.

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Unable to establish secure connection. Was remote cluster configured with SSL? [rmtAddr=/10.9.9.1:47501, errMsg="Remote host closed connection during handshake"]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendMessageDirectly(ServerImpl.java:1293)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1046)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:890)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:373)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1948)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1028)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:649)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpring.start(IgniteSpring.java:66)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean.afterSingletonsInstantiated(IgniteSpringBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:777)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1853)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.writeToSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1501)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1452)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1413)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendMessageDirectly(ServerImpl.java:1199)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    ... 41 more
2018-11-22 14:47:06.727  INFO  localhost-startStop-1 Log4JLogger Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
2018-11-22 14:47:11.733  INFO  localhost-startStop-1 Log4JLogger No verification for local node leave has been received from coordinator (will stop node anyway).
```

I've implemented custom IpFinder so it will NOT return IPs of other nodes until Ignite is fully online. It helped to get rid of this exception. And once they both fully initialized they're trying to talk to each other, but nothing happens -- they wont join the same cluster anyway.

```
2018-11-22 14:45:25.974  INFO  tcp-disco-srvr-#3 Log4JLogger TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1, rmtPort=43392]
2018-11-22 14:45:25.983  INFO  tcp-disco-srvr-#3 Log4JLogger TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1, rmtPort=43392]
2018-11-22 14:45:25.985  INFO  tcp-disco-sock-reader-#12 Log4JLogger Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1:43392, rmtPort=43392]
2018-11-22 14:45:25.993  INFO  tcp-disco-sock-reader-#12 Log4JLogger Received ping request from the remote node [rmtNodeId=b940dd90-0b94-42ba-b09a-5e0c7c8599e4, rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1:43392, rmtPort=43392]
2018-11-22 14:45:25.993  INFO  tcp-disco-sock-reader-#12 Log4JLogger Finished writing ping response [rmtNodeId=b940dd90-0b94-42ba-b09a-5e0c7c8599e4, rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1:43392, rmtPort=43392]
2018-11-22 14:45:25.994  INFO  tcp-disco-sock-reader-#12 Log4JLogger Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.160.1:43392, rmtPort=43392
```

UPD: Here is a [simple project](https://github.com/skarpushin/issue20181122) to help reproduce the issue

Comment: Can you file a ticket against Apache Ignite JIRA? This is not normal behavior.

Comment: @alamar, FYI: JIRA task created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-10388 and also I've created small project to help reproduce the issue: https://github.com/skarpushin/issue20181122

Comment: There is a VERY good chance that the cause of this issue is the same as discussed here: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Race-Condition-at-Grid-Startup-td13038.html